# Why does df on a specific mount iterate over all mounts?

Tags: linux, mount, disk-usage, debugging

When running `df /nfs/mount/point`, I expect that it will be faster than `df | grep /nfs/mount/point`, because it will not `stat` all other mount points.

But `strace` shows that `stat` is executed all NFS mounts and then the output is shown for the specific mount point.

Is this a bug? Or is there any deeper reason for going over all mount points?

I am seeing this with df version 8.4, on CentOS 6.6, with 2.6.32 kernel.

Sample output (with edits to remove company information)

```
$ strace df /home/user1/some/Directory
~  
~  
stat("/home/user2", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0  
stat("/home/user3", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0  
stat("/home/user4", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=36864, ...}) = 0  
stat("/home/user5", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=663552, ...}) = 0  
stat("/software/bin", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0  
stat("/scratch/space", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0  
stat("/eng/tools", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0  
~  
~
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce on `df` `8.21`, Ubuntu 14.04.2, kernel 3.13.0-58.

Comment: Is it just checking up the tree, ie `/nfs/mount/point`, `/nfs/mount`, `/nfs`?

Comment: @muru , good point, It is df 8.4 (I have updated the question)

Comment: @roaima , no , not just following the path, but iterating over ALL mount points.

Comment: Please include the relevant lines from the `stat` output that make you think it does this. You might just be misinterpreting the output of `strace` (I know I do half the time)

Comment: use the source, Luke! :)

Comment: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/df.c#n1681 -> http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/mountlist.c#n418

Comment: @terdon , added some sample output.

Comment: @Prem tip: use `strace -e stat df ...` to show just calls to `stat`.

Comment: OK, that certainly does look like a bug that has been fixed in newer versions. I only get those lines if I run `df` with no arguments.

Comment: For comparison (with the versions I mentioned in my first comment), I get this output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12878767/

Comment: @muru , nice tip ! It will be useful !

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been fixed in newer versions. With the `df` on my Debian system (`df` version 8.23), I get:

```
$ strace -e stat df >/dev/null 
stat("/sys", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/proc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=3920, ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/pts", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/run", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1360, ...}) = 0
stat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/lock", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/sys/fs/pstore", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/shm", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=220, ...}) = 0
stat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/mnt/bigboy", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/mnt/movies", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/sys/fs/fuse/connections", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/nfs_shares/lacoloc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0754, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0
stat("/nfs_shares/movies", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=24576, ...}) = 0
stat("/nfs_shares/music", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/nfs_shares/series", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/winblows", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0
stat("/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=520, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/rpc_pipefs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/sys/fs/cgroup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/cgmanager/fs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=240, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1000", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
stat("/proc/fs/nfsd", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/120", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=100, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1002", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1003", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1004", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1001", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=120, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1001/gvfs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0500, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/cgroup/cpu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=3920, ...}) = 0
stat("/run", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1360, ...}) = 0
stat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/lock", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/sys/fs/pstore", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/shm", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=220, ...}) = 0
stat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/mnt/bigboy", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/mnt/movies", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/winblows", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0
stat("/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=520, ...}) = 0
stat("/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/sys/fs/cgroup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/cgmanager/fs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=240, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1000", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
stat("/proc/fs/nfsd", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/120", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=100, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1002", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1003", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1004", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1001", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=120, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/user/1001/gvfs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0500, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/cgroup/cpu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

But only the target filesystem is examined when one is given:

```
$ strace -e stat df /home/ >/dev/null 
stat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Oh, nice to know that this is not seen on newer binaries , +1 , but it is still not clear if original issue is a bug or there is some Deliberate reason for this. If it is a bug, then it is fixed in newer binaries. If it was Deliberate , Eg to get some information X , then "they" have found a better, optimised way to get the information X , without going over all mount points.

Comment: @Prem good point. No idea, really. I assumed it was a bug simply because the newer one doesn't do this. I guess we'd need to look through the changelogs to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I will put this as a partial answer; I cannot say why the gnulib/coreutils developers chose to do it this way.

You can see in http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/df.c#n1681 that the df source code asks for the list of mounted filesystems. The source for this function, beginning at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/mountlist.c#n418, loops over every mounted filesystem (via /proc/self/mountinfo). Only later are explicitly-mentioned filesystems printed.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the code reference, that shows why I get the output , +1. Still, it is not clear if it is a bug or there is a Deliberate reason for this.

Comment: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/commit/?id=3ea43e02541ece750ffc6cd1dfe34195421b4ef3 may be the change in behavior -- committed at 2014-09-09 11:56:04 (GMT)